# Joomla No input file specified error on windows server

Tags: windows, iis, joomla

I run a Joomla 2.5 website on localhost. I didnt have any problems on localhost with sef urls but when I uploaded it on a windows server I got this:
No input file specified.

please help

Comment: This tutorial may help you: http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs_on_IIS

Comment: Thanks but I dont have access to the server

Comment: You have to contact your hosting company to help you.